# Dynamically adding row component to JSF 2 dataTable

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have a dataTable where each row represents an auction item, and a Bid button next to each item. When the user clicks the button I need to show a little bidding component with an input text, and a button to submit the bid. This "bidding" component needs to be right under the auction item the user is bidding on.

With regular HTML this is simple: just have another row, conditionally rendered under the auction item row. I know how to do this.

But dataTable is based on columns, and I need to dynamically render not a column, but a row (with colspan equals the number of columns in this dataTable.)

(I'm not sure if this is clear enough so I'll try saying it in other words: the dynamically inserted row does not have another auction item. It has a couple of other widgets.)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can achieve what you want with only original JSF's tags. In fact, it may be very difficult for you to develop such composite component on your own.

Fortunately, if you take a look at PrimeFaces's [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf), you will see a feature called `ExpandableRows`. Your table should look like this:

```
<h:form>  
    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{mrBean.itemsToBid}">  

        <f:facet name="header">  
             Items for Bidding  
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column style="width:16px">  
            <p:rowToggler />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Name" >
            #{item.name}
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Condition" >  
            #{item.condition} 
        </p:column>  

        <p:rowExpansion>  

            <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" > 
                <h:outputText value="Your bid:" />  
                <h:inputText  value="#{mrBean.bidAmount}" />  

                <h:commandButton actionListener="#{mrBean.bid(item)}" value="Bid"/>  
            </h:panelGrid>  

        </p:rowExpansion>  
    </p:dataTable>  
</h:form>
```

Your bidding form is inside the `<p:rowExpansion>` component and it does appear right below your item row.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. J4mes. Looks like this could work. But I need the rowToggler to be a command like with the text reading "Place Your Bid" and I don't need the little arrow. Can this be done?

Comment: One of the attribute of `<p:rowToggler />` is `class`. You can write a CSS button, for example, an image with the phrase `Place your bitch :P` and map it to this button.

Comment: Nice answer (+1 from me), but please remove h:outputText and use the expression directly in p:column ;)

Comment: @MikeBraun thks :P. Btw, `<p:column>` does not have any attributes for value. How can I put the expression directly in it? Besides, all the showcase for `<p:dataTable>` used `<h:outputText>` :P. I think it looks neater that way too.

Comment: Thanks again. Any chance for a code sample for this? I've always been a server side guy and never worked with css...

Comment: I think the following was meant: `<p:column headerText="Name" >        #{item.name}</p:column>`. `<h:outputText>` is only needed when you want to apply css, turn off escaping or when the parent component counts its children (like in the `<h:panelGrid>`)

Comment: @user1037343 I'm not very good with CSS too :P. I updated my answer with a simple CSS snippet. You may need to explore more on your own to make it look nicer ^^.

Comment: Actually, regarding the option to have the <p:rowToggler/> with a different image. I need this to be an *action* button. And I don't think the rowToggler can submit an action (other than toggling the row:) Any ideas where to go with this?

Comment: @user1037343 what kind of actions do you need? Btw, I think you can manage to do what you need with the form inside the expanded row.

Comment: @user1037343 and yes. I have just tested and I haven't found any ways that rowToggler can submit an action. You're gonna have to do it with the form inside the expanded row.

Comment: You are correct, Mr. J4ams. I can do the action from inside the expanded row and I don't need the toggler to do it. Now I should get the css working and I'm done.